# Close "URL wants to Know your location" in Playwright Python

Tags: playwright-python

How to close this popup?

It will be ideal to Deny my location.

I have tried with:

```
context = await browser.new_context(
    geolocation={"longitude": 20.967779, "latitude": -89.624260},
    permissions=["geolocation"]
)

permissions=["geolocation"]
context.grant_permissions(permissions)
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help?